# グーグルフォームを複数コピーがしたいです

Tags: google-apps-script

皆さまに教えて頂きたいことがあります。
ぜんぜんな素人な私なりに、数日あれこれ調べたのですが分かりませんでした。
分かられる方がいらっしゃいましたら、助けていただけたらと思いました。

タイトルにありますように、グーグルフォームを複数コピーがしたいのが、
実現したいことです。

スプレッドシートですと、調べて下記コードでうまく動かすことができました。
同じようにフォームをコピーしたいのですが、試行錯誤しましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
どなたかわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

－－－－－－－－－わたしの作ったスプレッドシートをコピーするスクリプト－－－－－

```
function myFunction() {

  for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("ここはURLを入れています");
  //var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(doc.getName());
  var copy = file.next().makeCopy();
    copy.setName(i +"てすとのこぴい-copy"); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

フォームを操作する際はFormAppを使います。

```
var doc = FormApp.openByUrl("ここはURLを入れています");
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
var copy = file.makeCopy();
```